# How to filter array of object and filter out values based on another array? Filtering should happen based on keys not values

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object which must be filtered based on another array, the keys are listed in the allowed array, pls help tired using object.entries and reduce but didn't work

```
const filter = _.filter;
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    row: [{
        id: 'a',
        name: 'ab',
        code: 'sdf',
        version: 1
      },
      {
        id: 'b',
        name: 'bc',
        code: 'def',
        version: 3
      },
      {
        id: 'c',
        name: 'cd',
        code: 'afd',
        version: 2
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    row: [{
        id: 'd',
        name: 'ef',
        code: 'sdf',
        version: 1
      },
      {
        id: 'e',
        name: 'gh',
        code: 'def',
        version: 3
      },
      {
        id: 'f',
        name: 'ij',
        code: 'afd',
        version: 2
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    row: [{
        id: 'g',
        name: 'kl',
        code: 'asd',
        version: 2
      },
      {
        id: 'h',
        name: 'mn',
        code: 'faf',
        version: 3
      },
      {
        id: 'i',
        name: 'op',
        code: 'dfs',
        version: 1
      },
    ]
  }
]

const allowed = ['id', 'name']

let result = [{
    id: 1,
    row: [{
        id: 'a',
        name: 'ab'
      },
      {
        id: 'b',
        name: 'bc'
      },
      {
        id: 'c',
        name: 'cd'
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    row: [{
        id: 'd',
        name: 'ef'
      },
      {
        id: 'e',
        name: 'gh'
      },
      {
        id: 'f',
        name: 'ij'
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    row: [{
        id: 'g',
        name: 'kl'
      },
      {
        id: 'h',
        name: 'mn'
      },
      {
        id: 'i',
        name: 'op'
      },
    ]
  }
]

result = data.filter(el => el.row.filter(elm => Object.fromEntries(allowed.map(k => [k, elm[k]]))));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You [deleted your old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70212991/how-to-filter-array-of-object-and-filter-out-values-based-on-another-array-filt) but there is still hardly any explanation in this one. We want to know what is supposed to happen without trying to reverse engineer the code.

Comment: tell me what u want to know? Im not doing any reverse engineering need to send to api only this 2 values. tried soo many options didnt work so posted in stackoverflow

Comment: i already have posted what i have tried need a bit of tweak in that.. pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new array with `Array.map`.

Logic

- Map through the array.
- Just spread operator to seperate out `row` key and rest of keys.
- return an object with rest of keys and row key as with the `Object.fromEntries`

```js
const data = [{
  id: 1,
  row: [
    { id: 'a', name: 'ab', code: 'sdf', version: 1 },
    { id: 'b', name: 'bc', code: 'def', version: 3 },
    { id: 'c', name: 'cd', code: 'afd', version: 2 },
  ]
},
{
  id: 2,
  row: [
    { id: 'd', name: 'ef', code: 'sdf', version: 1 },
    { id: 'e', name: 'gh', code: 'def', version: 3 },
    { id: 'f', name: 'ij', code: 'afd', version: 2 },
  ]
},
{
  id: 3,
  row: [
    { id: 'g', name: 'kl', code: 'asd', version: 2 },
    { name: 'mn', code: 'faf', version: 3 },
    { id: 'i', name: 'op', code: 'dfs', version: 1 },
  ]
}
]

const allowed = ['id', 'name'];

const result = data.map(({ row, ...rest }) => {
  return {
    ...rest,
    row: row.map(elm => Object.fromEntries(allowed.map(k => [k, elm[k]])))
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Long way but it works:

```js
const data = [
    {id: 1, row: [
            {id: 'a', name: 'ab', code: 'sdf', version: 1},
            {id: 'b', name: 'bc', code: 'def', version: 3},
            {id: 'c', name: 'cd', code: 'afd', version: 2},
        ]
    },
    {id: 2, row: [
            {id: 'd', name: 'ef', code: 'sdf', version: 1},
            {id: 'e', name: 'gh', code: 'def', version: 3},
            {id: 'f', name: 'ij', code: 'afd', version: 2},
        ]
    },
    {id: 3, row: [
            {id: 'g', name: 'kl', code: 'asd', version: 2},
            {id: 'h', name: 'mn', code: 'faf', version: 3},
            {id: 'i', name: 'op', code: 'dfs', version: 1},
        ]
    }
];

const allowed = ['id', 'name'];

let res = [];
data.forEach((el) => {
    let obj = {};
    obj.id = el.id;
    obj["row"] = [];
    let row = buildArray(el.row);
    obj["row"].push(row);
    res.push(obj);
})

function buildArray(row) {  
  r = {};
  allowed.forEach((k) => {    
    r[k] = row[0][k];
  })
  return r;
}
console.log(res)
```